ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' VSCode Debug mode
If new conda environment is created and tried to run visual studio code in debug mode, it fails to identify sklearn package although it is installed in environment
I tried to reinstall the package and relaunch VS code session but nothing worked. Finally I found interpreter was not selected to new environment, press (CTRL+SHIFT+P) and select interpreter according to your new environment, it should work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
